# How to upgrade Git in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: git, updates, msysgit, aptana-studio

I just did an update to Aptana Studio 3 to the latest version but unfortunately
it did not update the git binary in the built-in shell facility. How do I update
git (more precisely msysgit) in Aptana studio 3? Since yum or apt-get is not available,
I am not sure about what command I would have to run to do the update. Thanks.